# ScrollView or NewText is not infinite

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am making a changelog for my app and I inserted a bunch of text into `display.newText`. Is there a limit to the amount of characters `display.newText` can take or is it a problem in ScrollView? My code:

```
local widget = require( "widget" )
    scrollView = widget.newScrollView
    {
        hideBackground = true,
        hideScrollBar = true,
        left = 0,
        top = 170,
        width = display.contentWidth,
        height = contH - 300,
        topPadding = 150,
        bottomPadding = 20,
        horizontalScrollDisabled = true,
        verticalScrollDisabled = false,
    }

ChangeLogText = [[ ...a bunch of text here... ]]

ChangeLog = display.newText(ChangeLogText, contW / 2, 4730, contW - 100, 0, "Fonts/visitor1.ttf", 40)
scrollView:insert(ChangeLog)
```

I can see ~164 lines of text, but it just stops there... Is there a way to make it infinite?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just recently - too bad that such limitations are detailed nowhere in the API.

I started with [this github repository](https://github.com/coronalabs/framework-widget/tree/master/widgetLibrary), witch contains the full widget library of Corona SDK (it's no longer developed AFAIK), but managed to find nothing.

The workaround I eventually settled with, is to start with only the first part of the text inserted into the text display object, and then use scrollView [scrollListener](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newScrollView.html#basic-scrollview) to reload text whenever top/bottom limit is reached.

Part of scrollListener (`event.direction == "up"` is basically the mirror image of this):

```
elseif ( event.direction == "down" ) then 
    --check if limit is reached or close to it, y is from scrollView:getContentPosition(), -800 is arbitrary
    if ( event.limitReached ) or y > - 800 then print( "Reached top limit" )
        --firstS stores number of first visible sign of a string
        if chat.firstS > 1 then
            --copy string
            local shownText = stringText
            --update display object 
            chat.text = shownText

            local firstS, lastS

            --do while display object is too high - I found that scrollView stops scrolling ~25000 height
            while (chat.height) > 24000 do
                --basically cut the text in half
                firstS = chat.firstS - #shownText/4
                if firstS < 1 then firstS = 1 end
                lastS = firstS + #shownText/2

                shownText = string.sub( stringText, firstS, lastS)
                chat.text = shownText

            end

            chat.firstS = firstS
            chat.lastS = lastS
            --scroll to halfway position in no time for seamless transition
            mainView:scrollToPosition({y = -(chat.height)/2, time = 0})

        end
    end
end
```

This is an early version and needs some refinement, but I hope it helps. If you find anything better, let me know. Also, I display text from bottom, so you might need to adjust it accordingly.